# MySQL calculated column lagged return

Tags: php, mysql, lag, calculated-columns

I have a MySQL query with a calculated column in it.

For some reason on the first run, the query returns NULL in the calculated column.
On refresh (i.e. a second run), it returns the calculated value correctly.
How can I get rid of that lag?

Please see the query below:

```
SELECT @P0:=MAX(CASE WHEN t2.date IS NULL THEN t1.price ELSE NULL END),

@P1:=MAX(CASE WHEN t3.date IS NULL THEN t1.price ELSE NULL END),

ROUND(100*(@P1-@P0)/@P0,1) AS 'r1y'
/* The r1y above is the calculated column that is returned with lag*/

FROM (SELECT date, price FROM mytable
WHERE ticker='XYZ'
AND date>=@t1:=(SELECT DATE_SUB((SELECT MAX(date) FROM mytable), 
INTERVAL 1 YEAR))) AS t1

LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT date FROM mytable
where ticker='XYZ'
AND date>=@t1) AS t2 
ON (t1.date>t2.date)

LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT date FROM mytable
WHERE ticker='XYZ'
AND date>=@t1) AS t3 
ON (t1.date<t3.date)
```

When I move the calculation of 'r1y' out of MySQL and into the PHP part of the code, there is no lag of course. Still, it would be good to have all the calculations in MySQL.

### UPDATE

Here's the query that's easier and returns the same results with no lag (execution time is roughly the same):

```
SELECT 
@d1:=(SELECT MAX(date) FROM mytable WHERE ticker='XYZ' AND current=1),
@d2:=(SELECT MIN(date) FROM mytable WHERE ticker='XYZ' 
AND date>=DATE_SUB(@d1, INTERVAL 1 YEAR)),
@m1:=(SELECT price FROM mytable WHERE ticker='XYZ' AND date=@d1),
@m2:=(SELECT price FROM mytable WHERE ticker='XYZ' AND date=@d3),
ROUND(100*(@m1-@m2)/@m2, 1) as r1y
```

It would still be good to know the nature of the above mentioned lag, but this suggested solution works fine for me.

Comment: Just a try: Don't use the prepared statements and use aliases instead. Like this: SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN t2.date IS NULL THEN t1.price ELSE NULL END) AS P0,

MAX(CASE WHEN t3.date IS NULL THEN t1.price ELSE NULL END) AS P1,

ROUND(100*(P1-P0)/P0,1) AS 'r1y'

Comment: Thanks @bouscher,
unfortunately that didn't work (returned an error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the value of @t1 here:

```
FROM (SELECT date, price
      FROM mytable
      WHERE ticker='XYZ' AND
            date>=@t1:=(SELECT DATE_SUB((SELECT MAX(date) FROM mytable
                                        ), INTERVAL 1 YEAR
                                       )
                       )
    ) AS t1
```

You are then using it in the subsequent subqueries.

SQL does *not* guarantee the join processing order.  And neither does MySQL.  The reason your query is not working the first time is because the first subquery is not being executed first.

Probably the simplest fix is to repeat the subquery in each part of the original query -- but be sure there is an index on `date` so it evaluates very quickly.

Comment: Thank you Gordon, that makes sense now!